# SQL: finding the maximum average grouped by an ID

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider following dataset:

| id | name | mgr_id | salary | bonus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | 1 | 68000 | 10000 |
| 2 | Lucas | 2 | 29000 | null |
| 3 | Max | 1 | 50000 | 20000 |
| 4 | Zack | 2 | 30000 | null |

I now want to find the manager who pays his subordinates the highest average salary plus bonus. A manager is someone who is present in of the mgr_id cells. So in this example Paul and Lucas are managers because their id is present in the mgr_id column of themselves and Max for Paul and Zack for Lucas.
Basically I want MAX(AVG(salary + bonus)) and then grouped by the mgr_id. How can I do that?
I am using SQLite.

My expected output in this example would be simply the employee name 'Paul' because he has 2 subordinates (himself and Max) and pays them more than the other manager Lucas.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: What kind of server do you have? MYSQL, MSSQL etc etc?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: How do we know that Paul and Lucas are manager?  It seems the name column is the name of employees.

Comment: @jarlh Thats what I tried in the last paragraph. My expected result is simply "Paul", so I need a name.

Comment: @Stoff I'm using SQLite currently

Comment: @KotaMori We need know that because Max and Zack have the id of Paul and Lucas in their mgr_id-column. So Paul is the manager of himself and Max and Lucas is the manager of himself and Zack

Comment: @NoChance Please update your question with said info so that others who might be able to help is getting all the info! :)

Comment: @NoChance I see. I missed the id column.  Understood. Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance, the whole Paul row, or just the name column? (You see, this is why you should use the same proper table format as you used for the sample data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
       mrg_id
     , pay_avg
  FROM
     (
       SELECT mrg_id
            , AVG(salary + COALESCE(bonus,0)) pay_avg
         FROM <table>
        GROUP 
           BY mrg_id
     ) q
ORDER 
   BY pay_avg
      desc
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 t1.mgr_id,AVG((t1.salary)+(t1.bonus)) as tot_sal
from #tbl_emps as t1
group by t1.mgr_id
order by AVG((t1.salary)+(t1.bonus)) desc
```